# GET request to same page- jQuery form

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a small search engine, I am using a form like

```
form action="" method="get" id="searchForm">
<input type="search" name="search" id="searchQuery" value="<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" />
</form>
```

I am passing the search query to the same page. I want to prevent submitting the form if the text box value is null. 
So, I added a event handler for this form

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function() {
alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
if($('#searchQuery').val()==null)
{
return false;
}
});
```

But it doesnt seem to work, when I try using form action ="#" it works fine. Can someone suggest a workaround?

Comment: `if($('#searchQuery').val()==null)` should be `if($('#searchQuery').val()==="")`

Comment: It is still the same. I believe the problem is because I am sending the request to the same page. If I change the code like form action="#" the existing code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking against null, trim the value and check against an empty string.

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(event) {
 if($('#searchQuery').val().trim()=="")
 {
  return false;
 }
});
```

Note: using trim() ensures that the form doesn't submit if only whitespace is in the input text box.

Comment: It is still the same. I believe the problem is because I am sending the request to the same page. If I change the code like form action="#" the existing code works fine.

Comment: Seems to be working over here http://jsfiddle.net/pVMyd/2/ Also try getting rid of the action attribute `<form method="get" id="searchForm">`

Answer (score 0):

val() function return empty sting "" not null

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(event) {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    if($('#searchQuery').val()=="") {
       // Make form submit invalid
       return false;
    }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/utku/5fmXY/

Comment: Sorry my mistake,modified it.Still doesnt work. I believe the problem is because I am sending the request to the same page. If I change the code like form action="#" the existing code works fine.

Comment: I don't understand your problem but i added fiddle link for example